# Edited .conf to load new cert, nginx loads without errors but no sites work

Tags: windows, nginx, ssl, nginx-config

We have a nginx server running on Windows and it runs perfect no problems at all, I have two sites running on that server and they are both using Let's Encrypt certificates.

Because of some certificate issues on one of the sites using LE we have created a new COMODO certificate I have then like always combined the server cert, two intermediates and the root cert into a bundle and copied the .key file to the server as well.

The only change I have done to the .conf files that is running without any problems are changing the cert/key file paths to the new certificate. I restart the nginx server, it loads up fine without any errors but I can't reach any of my sites now.

It's like the new certificate crashes both site configurations even tho the change it only made to one of them.

I can change the filepath back to the LE certificate and then it works - So I'm pretty sure that the .conf file is correct, the sites is working so no firewall/port issues, so it seems to be something with the new certificate, but what can it be? How can it crash both sites when only configured for one? I'm a bit lost here and doesn't have lot to search without any errors.

Hope that someone might be able to point me in the correct direction.

Cheers
Kristian

Comment: Anything helpful in the nginx error log? What does `nginx -t` command say?

Comment: Nothing in the nginx error log, completely empty. I run nginx as a service on Windows, so I don't think that I can use commands. But when the server starts and runs without any errors, surely the configuration syntax must be correct. It works if I just change the certificate file and nothing else

Comment: Even being runned as a service, there is no problem to manually run configuration check (`nginx -t`) from the console window, no matter the service is started or not.

Comment: I got the command to run and everything looks okay

Enter PEM pass phrase:

nginx: the configuration file C:\nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok

nginx: configuration file C:\nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: You private key is protected with a passphrase? I'm not familiar with such a scenario, doesn't it mean you need to enter it every time you start the nginx service?

Comment: That was indeed the problem thanks!
I created the new csr and key in openSSL and used an parameter that set a PEM pass.